# kivy NumericProperty issue

Tags: python, kivy

I am working on incrementer app, and this is my code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

value = NumericProperty(0)

class documentScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(documentScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1
        self.inc = Button(text='++')
        self.add_widget(self.inc)
        self.add_widget(Label(text=str(value)))

class MainScreen(App):
    def build(self):
        return documentScreen()

if __name__=='__main__':
    MainScreen().run()
```

but when i an run the code, Label display as `<NumericProperty name=>` instead of 0.
It's doesn't display 0.

Comment: You don't need to use NumericProperty. And you're not using right. Also there are at least ten different threads asking the same question. Please take some time to look through the forums some more and you'll find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy properties are defined at class level. So you need to put your NumericProperty one line above the **init** method of your DocumentScreen class. You made it a global variable which doesn't make sense.